# Nesting directives, both with template url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I have 2 directives within a module.  Within one of them, is a templateUrl property.  Within that templateUrl, I've made a reference to the other directive, which in turn has a templateUrl.

e.g.

```
<div>    <!--This is my first partial page which uses the SelectorResult directive -->
  Here are some results
  <div result-carousel>
     <!-- here is where some more html should go from result-carousel -->
  </div>
</div>
```

From the module with the directives:

```
app.directive('SelectorResult', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {},
            templateUrl: '/chooser/Pages/partials/selector-result-tmpl.aspx',
            replace: true,
            controller: 'SelectorResultController',
            controllerAs: 'resultCtrl'
        };
    });

app.directive('resultCarousel', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/chooser/Pages/partials/carousel-tmpl.html'
        };
    });
```

This is the error I'm getting:
[ngTransclude:orphan] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/ngTransclude/orphan?p0=%3Cdivlass%3D%carousel-inner%22%20ng-transclude%3D%22%22%3E

I get an error about transclusion, and I've tried some things, but no change.  I thought you folks might have ideas.

Comment: Can you share the error please?

Comment: It's a bit confusing what the html shown represents ... is that inside the first template? Try adding comments about what html exists where.

Comment: The error indicates that you are using `ng-transclude` in one of the templates, but neither directive has a `transclude: true` property.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate for one to have it over the other?
I just saw that in the carousel-tmpl, there is a div with ng-tranclude attached to it.